# Dell U3014 suddenly has poor display quality without any apparent changes to the system

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, display-settings

My Dell U3014 has been working perfectly since I purchased it in 2015. This morning I started working and all of a sudden the picture on the Dell is noticeably worse than it was yesterday, the rendering looks horrible. I have two monitors hooked up to a HP Z440, a **Dell U3014** and a **HP Z23n** both using display port, the display is noticeably degraded on the **Dell U3014** and looks fine on the **HP Z23n**. This change is especially apparent with black text on a white background, but the change is not limited to just text everything looks worse.   Both displays looked fine yesterday, Windows did not install any updates (as far as I can tell) last night and I have not changed any settings.

I have tried/checked the following:

1. Switched cables - no effect
2. Reset the monitor to factory defaults - no effect
3. Made sure video settings were set to render clear type fonts and anti-aliased - all settings were correct

My question is has anyone else with a **Dell U3014** experienced a sudden drop in display fidelity? Given the fact that my **HP Z23n** looks fine and my **Dell U3014** looks horrible my guess is that it is a hardware problem with the Dell, but the monitor is only 5 years old and isn't used 24/7 so I would hope it has a longer life than just 5 years.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have swapped the two monitors between their ports and the problem is still
there, then the problem is surely hardware.

Five years is a good lifetime for some monitors, while others may go much further.
This is a matter of luck.

Comment: Just to update, the problem was hardware, but not the monitor the video card :) Swapped out to a new video card and BOOM! everything was back to normal. Thanks for the reply!